# is there any Designation called 'LEAD'

Tags: promotion

Recently i am promoted.In promotion letter the designation mentioned as **'LEAD'.**,but i can't find these designation used by any organization.Is there any organization using the designation **'LEAD'**

Comment: So why not ask HR?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? *Your* organization does use it, why do you want others to use it?

Comment: Company-specific. Ask manager/HR/colleague.

Comment: There isn't a standard set of job titles used by all companies.

Comment: So are you going to turn down the promotion is you don't get clarity on title?

Comment: You ever seen a animated show or movie? Most of the time they have "Lead" something as a credit. I'm not sure what the big deal is though.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is **Yes**. For example *we* do. we have "Lead Developer"s and "Lead Architect"s. Someone with the title "Lead ..." leads a group of people that are of the designated title. A lead architect leads the architects for example.

The longer answer is: **who cares**. *Your organisation* needs to know what the title means and what it *wants* the title to mean. As long is that is clear, your title could be *"the pink elephant in charge of ..."* and it would not change anything.

Comment: my problem is the designation simply mentioned as "Lead". so i simply want to know if any organization out there use this designation. if it's not common i can ask my HR to update the same

Comment: @Rajaram If you are so concerned with exact terms then why not start with proper capitalization.

Comment: Yes, there are orgs which use this, formally or informally. What they mean by it may differ.